# enforcing an extension method to be available

Tags: c#

I want to enforce conversion between my model classes and their corresponding protobuf messages.

A little example how I wanted it in my head:

```
abstract class MessageExtension<T1, T2> where T1 : ModelBase where T2 : Google.Protobuf.IMessage
{
        public abstract T2 ToMessage(this T1 obj);
}
```

This causes a CS1106 because extension methods may not be defined in a static or generic class.

How can I achieve this without causing an error?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: without looking into it in detail, I had a (probably) similar requirement recently, and we ended up using composition (partial class) instead of extension or inheritance, because either doesn't play well with what the protobuf compiler outputs.

Comment: partial classes would be a solution to the problem, but I don't want to use them because I want to have grpc and entity framework parts of the project agnostic from the others